# ASP.NET MVC - Cannot insert duplicate key row in object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a problem with Entity Framework Core. I have 2 models:
Category.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Category | ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Name is Required")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
```

And LibraryItem.cs

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category Id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Id is Required")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Author, Speaker or Director")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Creator of the media is required")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public int? Pages { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("DVD or Audiobook Length")]
    public int? RunTimeMinutes { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Available to borrow")]
    public bool IsBorrowable { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name of Borrower")]
    public string Borrower { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date of the Borrow")]
    public DateTime? date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Type of Media")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type of Media is Required")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
```

LibraryItem has a Foreign key of CategoryId, which is the Primary key for the Category table.
I wanna add two items with the same foreign key. So the two items are within the same Category.
But when I try to add another one with the same CategoryId I get this error

```
cannot insert duplicate key row in object
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?
Many thanks!

Comment: Please refrain from adding "SOLVED" or similar to your questions title.  Instead, accept the answer you've received.  Please see [Why does Stack Overflow discourage adding “Solved” to question titles?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-does-stack-overflow-discourage-adding-solved-to-question-titles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you created one-to-one relation, but you need one-to-many

You have to fix you Category class:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Category | ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Name is Required")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Library.Category))]
    public virtual ICollection<LibraryItem> LibraryItems {get; set:}
```

After fixing you will have to make a migration again

Answer (score 1):

You have to let EF know that these two entities are related in a one to many relationship by adding the navigation properties on each class:

```
    public class Category {
        ...
        
        public virtual ICollection<LibraryItem> LibraryItems {get; set;}
    }


    public class LibraryItem {
        ...
        
        [DisplayName("Category Id")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category Id is Required")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

If you add the navigation properties, you can use the Fluent API to manually configure relationships inside your DbContext's OnModelCreating method

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LibraryItem>()
            .HasOne(l => l.Category)
            .WithMany(c => c.LibraryItems);
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for explaining it to me, it makes sense now. :)